# Why "ParentBackground" doesn't work at Windows Classic theme ? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, background, themes, parent

i use a toolbar and a panel on my form .

**First picture** : Windows 7 Normal theme , ParentBackground for Panel = True :

[image]

**Second picture** : Windows 7 Classic theme , ParentBackground for Panel = True :

[image]

*Why "ParentBackground" property doesn't work at Windows Classic theme ? and how can i solve this problem ?*

Comment: What happens when your user has a non-default colour scheme?  Do you still use a grey gradient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better idea : **Using Gradient Panel** . i resize it and match it within Toolbar :D

[Thank you all]

Answer (score 6):

[`ParentBackground`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.ParentBackground) is exclusively for themes. If you don't have themes enabled, then it does nothing. The help says so:

> Determines whether control uses parent's theme background.
>
> If ParentBackground is true, the control uses the parent's theme background to draw its own background. ParentBackground has no effect unless XP themes are enabled.

You're looking for [`ParentColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.ParentColor) instead.

Comment: Thank you for response ! but i don't use the "Color" property of toolbar . is use "GradientColorStart" and "GradientColorStop" properties . and as you know the "ParentColor" property gets parent color from "Color" propery of toolbar !

Comment: just switch the gradient off in Classic, after all practically nobody uses Classic anyway so why get hot and bothered about the appearance under Classic

Comment: Non-themed views are used more often that you might expect, @David. It's an easy way to reduce bandwidth requirements when using Remote Desktop. But I agree that disabling the gradient is a good idea; it will fit in better with the non-themed appearance.

Comment: I don't see why turning off themes makes much difference to remote session performance since it's only the GDI that goes over the wire

Comment: All server products have themes off by default.